# How to execute a Python script in Node.js with sudo privillege

Tags: python, node.js

The script create some files in directories which need sudo permissions and executes few command that also need sudo privillage.

I want to execute that script giving sudo privillage.

Is there any way to do that ?

I am trying to execute it with python-shell module as well as spawn child process.

Comment: What do you need to do that needs root privileges? Is there no way around this?

Comment: @Attie Like any service reload and copying file in some safe sytem folder.

Comment: Have you looked at `/etc/sudoers`? You can be quite specific about what is permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got any answer on it, So I researched it on my own. The besy way to run any shell command or script is by using node-cmd moudle. It works soo bright .
Just run the node script with sudo privillege, and you are good to go .

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to give sudo, as a hacker could do anything if there is any security issues. You could give the user witch runs the web server the permission to do the task your task is intending to do.

In general try to avoid root whenever you can.

Comment: Thanks @danny for your suggestion, but i have clearly mentioned that i need to perform some task that would be needing sudo privillege.